# Where does Zexy Zek get the extra commands?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-mods

I watch Zexy Zek's [trolling videos](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL1BEBA16C08C71975), and he always uses these new commands  such as `/nick`, `/d`, `/punish`, `/pt`, etc. Is there a mod for these commands? If so, then can anybody tell me where to get it?

Comment: Is this a troll question? The link is not even valid! Before posting a question or answer, you should learn more about Markdown and the formatting. Mabye you ment ` [The video] [1]` and `[1]: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL1BEBA16C08C71975`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ZexyZek has done a video on what plugins he uses to troll people in his Minecraft trolling series.

Please bear in mind that all these plugins are **plugins that work on Bukkit servers only, they are not mods, and ZexyZek does not use any mods in his trolling videos, he uses Bukkit server plugins**.

He gives the plugins he uses in the description of his [trolling tips + tricks video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p2LSTooBRJE) (these do not appear to be all of the ones he has used):

> Plugins used:
>
> Essentials - http://bit.ly/rIEdG5
>
> WorldEdit - http://bit.ly/qrIyhJ
>
> DisguiseCraft - http://bit.ly/Pd7IBH
>
> These are basically all you need! :D

I have found some other Bukkit server plugins which ZexyZek has used in his trolling videos:

- [Punishmental](http://www.curse.com/bukkit-plugins/minecraft/punishmental)
- [iControlU](http://www.planetminecraft.com/mod/icontrolu/)

All of these plugins put together should give you all the commands you want as they are the plugins ZexyZek has used in his trolling series on YouTube.

Comment: Is there a way I can get these on singleplayer, without a server? If so tell me how.

Comment: Not to my knowledge, no. You can create a bukkit server on your own computer and play on that though.

Comment: Do you know which plugin has the /pt command?

Comment: I'm not sure which one has that particular command, no. You can download all the plugins and try them out for the commands you're looking for though.

Comment: @LigitGaming5 The plugin which has the /pt command is Essentials.